# nodejs-async: return mysql query result in for loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have three operations to do one after another

1.Fetch some rows from db

2.Another mysql query in forloop for getting some data and store in variable

3.Display the data

For that i am using `async` `waterfall` method.

```
async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                //first sql and pass the result to second function
                collection.getAllCollections(function (status,error,result) {
                    callback(null,result);
                });
            },
           //running another query in loop with result with previous
            function(result, callback){
                for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                    collection.getImages(result[i].id,function (status,error,user) {
                        //append the query result to old result
                         result[i]['users'] = user;
                    });
                }
                callback(null,result);
            }
        ], function (err, result) {

            console.log("result",result);
        });
```

But the problem final `result` does not contains the `user` results because the second query(query in for loop is asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

You realised the problem at hand. Your callback basically has to wait for the for loop to end.
For example like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(next){
        //first sql and pass the result to second function
        collection.getAllCollections(function (status,error,result) {
            next(null, result);
        });
    },
    function(result, next){
        var calls = [];

        //putting every call in an array
        result.forEach(function(resultObject){
            calls.push(function(callback) {
                collection.getImages(resultObject.id, function (status, error, user) {
                     resultObject['users'] = user;
                     callback(null, resultObject);
                });
            }
        )});

        //performing calls async parallel to each other
        async.parallel(calls, function(err, results) {
            //executed as soon as all calls are finished
            if (err) {
                next(err, null);
            } else {
                next(null, results);
            }
        });
    }
], function (err, result) {

    console.log("result",result);
});
```

Documentation: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel

Comment: But where can put `isDone` function?? i am using  async waterfall method

Comment: @Jabaa I updated my code to clarify my solution. This should work but I didn't test it.

Comment: @Jabaa I updated my answer again. There is a better, cleaner and more efficient solution with async.parallel available. That should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks let me try it

Comment: @Jabaa please accept my answer if it works for you :)